# Pandas, string case statement to dataframe - More then two conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe where I am trying to insert a column and have what is equivalent to a case statement based on another column within the dataframe.

Case statement logic:

`Case When column a IN ('Stack','Overflow') THEN 'St' WHEN column a IN ('Super','User') THEN 'Su'`

what I have:

```
final_df["business_name"] = np.where[(final_df['column a'].isin(('Stack', \
                                                'Overflow')),'St', "")
```

I want to add an & to do another condition.

`& (final_df['column a'].isin(('Super')), 'Su', "")]`

Sample data:

```
+----------+----------------+
| column a | business_name  |
+----------+----------------+
| Stack    | St             |
| Overflow | St             |
| Super    | Su             |
| User     | Su             |
+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: It feels like you've asked this before.

Comment: yes i have, thought i would give it another shot.

Comment: You posted a comment under an answer of mine. That definitely should have worked for you.

Comment: i asked the wrong question

Comment: use `np.where(df['column a'].isin(('Stack','Overflow')),'St','Su')` or `np.select([df['column a'].isin(('Stack','Overflow')),df['column a'].isin(('Super','User'))],['St','Su'])`

Comment: thanks for this. What if I have more then 2 conditions?